# Design test class dependent on current datetime, 24 hours a day, seven days a week

Tags: test-design, unit-tests, tdd

I need to create a test to verify my `NewBusinessDateTime.calculate(Integer hoursToAdd)` works. The sudo code of what `calculate()` does is:

```
IF currentDateTime.addHours(hoursToAdd) IS WITHIN BUSINESS HOURS
RETURN currentDateTime.addHours(hoursToAdd)

ELSE
RETURN nextDateTimeBusinessIsOpenRightWhenBusinessOpens
```

The business hours are

```
//  M-F 8 AM - 8 PM
//  SAT 10 AM - 4 PM
//  SUN Closed
```

What would be the most effective way to write a test to cover every possible time, 24 hours a day, 7 days week? Or is that desire too excessive? Unfortunately in my production code, I'm getting reports from users saying what `NewBusinessDateTime.calculate(Integer hoursToAdd)` is outputting is sometimes in the past, too far into the future, and other unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 3):

You can use some [Boundary Value Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary-value_analysis) to filter out the list of test cases.
You would probably do a better risk analysis than anyone else in this case, but I can imagine the following as the riskiest test cases:

Monday 8 AM
Monday 8 AM +- 1s

Monday 8 PM
Monday 8 PM +- 1s

Saturday 10 AM
Saturday 10 AM +- 1 s

Saturday 4 PM
Saturday 4 PM +- 1s

Some assumptions in this list:

- You can update the time at the second level. If it comes only at minutes level (type checking), you can change the variation to 1 minute;
- It assumes that all week days are more or less the same case, therefore, testing only Monday is ok;
- It assumes Saturday may cause some unique problems; if not, testing only Monday is ok.

Additionally:

- Be sure `addHours` is [a pure function](https://www.sitepoint.com/functional-programming-pure-functions/). If not, when you call it twice (on the *if* and inside it), you would be adding the time twice.
- Be sure that `nextDateTimeBusinessIsOpenRightWhenBusinessOpens` is working properly. IMO, it should receive `currentDateTime` - a bug may be hidden there if it depends on another form of getting the current date.

Comment: Your **Additionally** section seems more relevant/interesting considering the problem! @joão-farias